# How do I keep the attribute from removing the class after being clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I was wondering how I keep the attribute to not remove the class once it's been clicked on, as I use a class for styling my buttons (bootstrap)

```
function resetButtons()
{
    document.getElementById('snog').removeAttribute('class');
    document.getElementById('marry').removeAttribute('class');
    document.getElementById('avoid').removeAttribute('class');
}
```

Here is the buttons codes

```
$('#snog').click(function() {
    resetButtons();
    document.getElementById('snog').setAttribute('class','selected');
    document.getElementById('answer_type').value = 1;
    showForm();
    console.log("Snog selected");
});

$('#marry').click(function() {
    resetButtons();
    document.getElementById('marry').setAttribute('class','selected');
    document.getElementById('answer_type').value = 2;
    showForm();
    console.log("Marry selected");
});

$('#avoid').click(function() {
    resetButtons();
    document.getElementById('avoid').setAttribute('class','selected');
    document.getElementById('answer_type').value = 3;
    showForm();
    console.log("Avoid selected");
});
```

And, the HTML with the classes

```
<div class="form-group text-center">
<input type="button" id="snog" class="btn btn-lg btn-success" value="Snog" sma_value="1">
<input type="button" id="marry" class="btn btn-lg btn-success" value="Marry" sma_value="2">
<input type="button" id="avoid" class="btn btn-lg btn-success" value="Avoid" sma_value="3">
```

Sorry for the blunt question/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `removeAttribute` and `setAttribute` use jQuery functions [`removeClass`](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/) and [`addClass`](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/).

```
$('#snog').removeClass('selected');
```

```
$('#snog').addClass('selected');
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple way. After you remove all class put it back again.

```
$(".form-group input").each(function() {
```

$(this).addClass("btn btn-lg btn-success");

});